# PHP - While loop, group by date?

Tags: php, html

I have below while loop:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

$history = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM softbox_bookings ORDER BY time DESC");
$history->execute(); 
while($row = $history->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    echo '<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>';

}
</table>
```

Which outputs, very simple:

```
07/05/2017  Name
07/05/2017  Name
29/04/2017  Name
```

As you can see, above output have two dates that are the same. My question is how can I group these dates together? So the two first identical dates, will show in one table, and the last date will show in it's own table?

Like this:

```
table 1:
07/05/2017  Name
07/05/2017  Name

table 2:
29/04/2017  Name
```

Is this even possible, using a while loop?

Comment: Well I think you need to write a FLOC

Comment: How does that code result in that output!! You use `$row` in the header but that variable has not been defined until you execute the query and start returning result rows???????

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ah sorry about that. Updated my question.

Comment: Well thats no better, now you dont actually output a date ANYWHERE in your code.

Comment: Please show real code. PSEUDO Code will only generate PSEUDO answers

Comment: Above code will output that. I have tried to SIMPLIFY my question.

Comment: Ahh, now that code wont generate the output you show.

Comment: Well we are back to me first comment. You need to write a Few Lines Of Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example a new table is opened every time the date change

```
$tableOpened = false;
$lastDate = null;
$history = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM softbox_bookings ORDER BY time DESC");
$history->execute(); 
while($row = $history->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    if ($lastDate !== $row['date']) {
        if ($tableOpened) {
            echo '</tbody></table>';//close previous opened table
        }

        //open new table
        echo '<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>';
        $tableOpened = true;
    }

    //table content
    echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';


    $lastDate = $row['date'];
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

$history = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(date) FROM softbox_bookings ORDER BY time DESC");
$history->execute(); 
while($row = $history->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $values = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM softbox_bookings WHERE date=".$row['date']." ORDER BY time DESC")->execute();
    echo '<tbody><tr>';

    while($values = $history->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         echo '<td>'.$row["date"].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$values["name"].'</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr></tbody>';

}
</table>
```